# CentOS6 - Backup all RPMs and installed programs

Tags: backup, package, rpm, restore, centos6

Is there away to backup all installed applications/RPMs/packages/ (even repositories)  as is (with same exact versions/patches) on 1 script that can re-install them on a fresh bare bone server of the same specs

Note:  I can't do any image or CloneZilla tricks
Note: there are some 3rd party software that is not offered by any repos ... solution should contain a backup of these packages (preferably all)

thanks!

Comment: You can easily backup the RPM *database* with something like this: `cd /var/lib; tar czvf $(hostname).rpmdatabase.tar.gz rpm`

Answer (score 0):

As noted in a comment, you can backup the RPM *database*, but that is only one part of replicating your configuration to another server:

- RPM's database records *almost* all of the information regarding the packages you have installed.  Using the database, you could in principle do something like a script that used `cpio` or `pax` to append all of the files known to the RPM database to a suitably large archive area.  `rpm -qa` gives a list of packages, and `rpm -ql`*package* gives a list of files for the given package.
- However, RPM's database does not necessarily record files created by package `%pre` and `%post` scripts.
- Likewise, it does not record working data (such as a MySQL database) that may be in `/var/lib`.

To handle those last two cases, you are going to have to do some analysis of your system to ensure that you do not leave something behind.  `rpm -qf`*pathname* can tell you who owns a given file- or directory.  What you have to do is to check for cases where RPM does not know who owns it.